# Gson: Directly convert String to JsonObject (no POJO)

Tags: java, json, gson

Can't seem to figure this out.
I'm attempting JSON tree manipulation in GSON, but I have a case where I do not know or have a POJO to convert a string into, prior to converting to `JsonObject`. Is there a way to go directly from a `String` to `JsonObject`?

I've tried the following (Scala syntax):

```
val gson = (new GsonBuilder).create

val a: JsonObject = gson.toJsonTree("""{ "a": "A", "b": true }""").getAsJsonObject
val b: JsonObject = gson.fromJson("""{ "a": "A", "b": true }""", classOf[JsonObject])
```

but `a` fails, the JSON is escaped and parsed as a `JsonString` only, and
`b` returns an empty `JsonObject`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Beware of gson validation pitfalls: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43233898/how-to-check-if-json-is-valid-in-java-using-gson/47890960#47890960

Answer (score 561, accepted):

use JsonParser; for example:

```
JsonObject o = JsonParser.parseString("{\"a\": \"A\"}").getAsJsonObject();
```

Comment: ugh should have a static 1 liner convenience method

Comment: no static example, but plenty of one liner examples below

Comment: the cast to JsonObject is unnecessary, better use `new JsonParser().parse(..).getAsJsonObject();`

Comment: I think [...].getAsJsonObject() is the right implementation. Casting seems like an overkill to me and not too clean.

Comment: Note that it can throw 3 exceptions per the [docs](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonParser.html#parse(com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader))

Comment: I guess JsonParser is an abstract class

Comment: @KevinMeredith you link is broken ,use [this](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/JsonParser.html#parse-java.lang.String-) please

Comment: Dallan Quass - I have a class with many static methods which can make different api calls. Should I have one instance of JsonParser for the class or should I create one in each static method ?

Comment: @MasterJoe2 I'm hoping others will answer your question, or maybe you want to post it as a new question? I haven't been around java for awhile.

Comment: Note that this method is now deprecated. Use `JsonParser.parseString(str).getAsJsonObject()`.

Comment: In my case, i needed it as string, so i used this:
`String data = new Gson().toJson(JsonParser.parseString("{type: someValue}"));`

Comment: This seems like it could be a performance hit if you have to parse the string when you already have knowledge that it's a `JsonPrimitve`. But I don't see another way.

Answer (score 150):

Try to use `getAsJsonObject()` instead of a straight cast used in the accepted answer:

```
JsonObject o = new JsonParser().parse("{\"a\": \"A\"}").getAsJsonObject();
```

Comment: For some reason it wraps with `members` parent key.  Here is a sample

       {
  "members" : {
   "key1" : "13756963814f2c594822982c0307fb81",
   "key2" : true,
   "key3" : 123456789
  }
 }

Comment: Use the latest gson library, like 2.2.4. The version like 2.2.2 adds members tag for some reason.

Comment: JsonParser().parse() is deprecated in newer versions of Gson. Use `JsonObject jsonObj = JsonParser.parseString(str).getAsJsonObject()`or 
`Gson gson = new Gson(); JsonElement element = gson.fromJson (jsonStr, JsonElement.class); JsonObject jsonObj = element.getAsJsonObject();`

Answer (score 62):

```
String jsonStr = "{\"a\": \"A\"}";

Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonElement element = gson.fromJson (jsonStr, JsonElement.class);
JsonObject jsonObj = element.getAsJsonObject();
```

Comment: can you validate my answer with GSON way for convert List data to jsonobject by gson  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18442452/create-an-array-of-json-objects/18443395#18443395

Comment: I have validated your answer.

Comment: @knoxxs, You mean `JsonObject` class definition? It comes from Google's Gson library. You can refer the documentation [here](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/index.html).

Comment: This gives me an error complaining about JsonElement not having a no-arg constructor.

Answer (score 43):

The simplest way is to use the `JsonPrimitive` class, which derives from `JsonElement`, as shown below:

```
JsonElement element = new JsonPrimitive(yourString);
JsonObject result = element.getAsJsonObject();
```

Comment: This is the simplest answer and helped me out.  Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Just encountered the same problem.  You can write a trivial custom deserializer for the `JsonElement` class:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;

GsonBuilder gson_builder = new GsonBuilder();
gson_builder.registerTypeAdapter(
        JsonElement.class,
        new JsonDeserializer<JsonElement>() {
            @Override
            public JsonElement deserialize(JsonElement arg0,
                    Type arg1,
                    JsonDeserializationContext arg2)
                    throws JsonParseException {

                return arg0;
            }
        } );
String str = "{ \"a\": \"A\", \"b\": true }";
Gson gson = gson_builder.create();
JsonElement element = gson.fromJson(str, JsonElement.class);
JsonObject object = element.getAsJsonObject();
```

Answer (score 7):

The `JsonParser` constructor has been deprecated. Use the static method instead:

```
JsonObject asJsonObject = JsonParser.parseString(someString).getAsJsonObject();
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is a more easy approach:

```
public class HibernateProxyTypeAdapter implements JsonSerializer<HibernateProxy>{

    public JsonElement serialize(HibernateProxy object_,
        Type type_,
        JsonSerializationContext context_) {
        return new GsonBuilder().create().toJsonTree(initializeAndUnproxy(object_)).getAsJsonObject();
        // that will convert enum object to its ordinal value and convert it to json element

    }

    public static <T> T initializeAndUnproxy(T entity) {
        if (entity == null) {
            throw new 
               NullPointerException("Entity passed for initialization is null");
        }

        Hibernate.initialize(entity);
        if (entity instanceof HibernateProxy) {
            entity = (T) ((HibernateProxy) entity).getHibernateLazyInitializer()
                    .getImplementation();
        }
        return entity;
    }
}
```

And then you will be able to call it like this:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(HibernateProxy.class, new HibernateProxyTypeAdapter())
        .create();
```

This way all the hibernate objects will be converted automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Came across a scenario with remote sorting of data store in EXTJS 4.X where the string is sent to the server as a JSON array (of only 1 object).
Similar approach to what is presented previously for a simple string, just need conversion to JsonArray first prior to JsonObject.

String from client: **[{"property":"COLUMN_NAME","direction":"ASC"}]**

```
String jsonIn = "[{\"property\":\"COLUMN_NAME\",\"direction\":\"ASC\"}]";
JsonArray o = (JsonArray)new JsonParser().parse(jsonIn);

String sortColumn = o.get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("property").getAsString());
String sortDirection = o.get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("direction").getAsString());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//import com.google.gson.JsonObject;  
JsonObject complaint = new JsonObject();
complaint.addProperty("key", "value");
```

Comment: Above is the easiest way to convert your key-value data to gson object.

Comment: Thanks, in my case I had an unparsed JSON string which I needed to start from.

Answer (score 1):

`com.google.gson.JsonParser#parse(java.lang.String)` is now deprecated

so use `com.google.gson.JsonParser#parseString`, it works pretty well

Kotlin Example:

```
val mJsonObject = JsonParser.parseString(myStringJsonbject).asJsonObject
```

Java Example:

```
JsonObject mJsonObject = JsonParser.parseString(myStringJsonbject).getAsJsonObject();
```