# JSON parsing using Gson for Java

Tags: java, json, gson

I would like to parse data from JSON which is of type `String`.
I am using [Google Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

I have:

```
jsonLine = "
{
 "data": {
  "translations": [
   {
    "translatedText": "Hello world"
   }
  ]
 }
}
";
```

and my class is:

```
public class JsonParsing{

   public void parse(String jsonLine) {

      // there I would like to get String "Hello world"

   }

}
```

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4110664/gson-directly-convert-string-to-jsonobject-no-pojo

Answer (score 263, accepted):

This is simple code to do it, I avoided all checks but this is the main idea.

```
 public String parse(String jsonLine) {
    JsonElement jelement = new JsonParser().parse(jsonLine);
    JsonObject  jobject = jelement.getAsJsonObject();
    jobject = jobject.getAsJsonObject("data");
    JsonArray jarray = jobject.getAsJsonArray("translations");
    jobject = jarray.get(0).getAsJsonObject();
    String result = jobject.get("translatedText").getAsString();
    return result;
}
```

To make the use more generic - you will find that [Gson's javadocs](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson) are pretty clear and helpful.

Comment: JsonObject extends JsonElement, so it is both.

Comment: the first line throws cannot instantiate of the type JsonParser on version gson-2.2.4.jar

Comment: String result = jobject.get("translatedText").toString(); This results will include the double quotes. String result = jobject.get("translatedText").getAsString(); doesn't include the quotes.

Comment: Al I the only one who thinks Gson overcomplicates things 98% of the time?  A simple JSONObject would do, but we all hate try/catch that much?

Comment: I need to use the parser class, however, I am getting the MalformedJsonException, so I have to be able to do SetLeinient with JsonParser. How?

Comment: @IllegalArgument 
It deprecated. No need to instantiate this class, use the static methods instead as `JsonParser.parse(jsonString);`

Answer (score 122):

In my first gson application I avoided using additional classes to catch values
mainly because I use json for config matters

despite the lack of information (even gson page), that's what I found and used:

starting from

```
Map jsonJavaRootObject = new Gson().fromJson("{/*whatever your mega complex object*/}", Map.class)
```

Each time gson sees a {}, it creates a Map (actually a gson StringMap )

Each time gson sees a '', it creates a String

Each time gson sees a number, it creates a Double

Each time gson sees a [], it creates an ArrayList

You can use this facts (combined) to your advantage

Finally this is the code that makes the thing

```
        Map<String, Object> javaRootMapObject = new Gson().fromJson(jsonLine, Map.class);

    System.out.println(
        (
            (Map)
            (
                (List)
                (
                    (Map)
                    (
                        javaRootMapObject.get("data")
                    )
                 ).get("translations")
            ).get(0)
        ).get("translatedText")
    );
```

Answer (score 21):

Simplest thing usually is to create matching Object hierarchy, like so:

```
public class Wrapper {
   public Data data;

   static class Data {
      public Translation[] translations;
   }
   static class Translation {
      public String translatedText;
   }
}
```

and then bind using GSON, traverse object hierarchy via fields. Adding getters and setters is pointless for basic data containers.

So something like:

```
Wrapper value = GSON.fromJSON(jsonString, Wrapper.class);
String text = value.data.translations[0].translatedText;
```

Comment: Then your object structure is NOT matching JSON.

Comment: why Data and Translation class static even if Wrapper is not?

Comment: I think that's a typo sort of: `Data` and `Translation` only need to be `static` if they are inner classes.

Comment: Changed slightly so that `static` modifier makes sense.

Answer (score 15):

You can create corresponding java classes for the json objects. The integer, string values can be mapped as is. Json can be parsed like this-

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create(); 
Response r = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Response.class);
```

Here is an example- http://rowsandcolumns.blogspot.com/2013/02/url-encode-http-get-solr-request-and.html

Answer (score 10):

You can use a separate class to represent the JSON object and use `@SerializedName` annotations to specify the field name to grab for each data member:

```
public class Response {

   @SerializedName("data")
   private Data data;

   private static class Data {
      @SerializedName("translations")
      public Translation[] translations;
   }

   private static class Translation {
      @SerializedName("translatedText")
      public String translatedText;
   }

   public String getTranslatedText() {
      return data.translations[0].translatedText;
   }
}
```

Then you can do the parsing in your parse() method using a `Gson` object:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Response response = gson.fromJson(jsonLine, Response.class);

System.out.println("Translated text: " + response.getTranslatedText());
```

With this approach, you can reuse the `Response` class to add any other additional fields to pick up other data members you might want to extract from JSON -- in case you want to make changes to get results for, say, multiple translations in one call, or to get an additional string for the detected source language.

Answer (score 9):

One way would be created a JsonObject and iterating through the parameters. For example

```
JsonObject jobj = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, JsonObject.class);
```

Then you can extract bean values like:

```
String fieldValue = jobj.get(fieldName).getAsString();
boolean fieldValue = jobj.get(fieldName).getAsBoolean();
int fieldValue = jobj.get(fieldName).getAsInt();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

**Using Gson to Solve**
I would create a class for individual parameter in the json String. Alternatively you can create one main class called "Data" and then create inner classes similarly. I created separate classes for clarity.

The classes are as follows.

- Data
- Translations
- TranslatedText

In the class JsonParsing the method "parse" we call `gson.fromJson(jsonLine, Data.class)` which will convert the String in java objects using Reflection.

Once we have access to the "Data" object we can access each parameter individually.

Didn't get a chance to test this code as I am away from my dev machine. But this should help.

**Some good examples and articles.**
http://albertattard.blogspot.com/2009/06/practical-example-of-gson.html 
http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide

**Code**

```
public class JsonParsing{

       public void parse(String jsonLine) {

           Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
           Data data = gson.fromJson(jsonLine, Data.class);

           Translations translations = data.getTranslation();
           TranslatedText[] arrayTranslatedText = translations.getArrayTranslatedText(); //this returns an array, based on json string

           for(TranslatedText translatedText:arrayTranslatedText )
           {
                  System.out.println(translatedText.getArrayTranslatedText());
           }
       }

    }


    public class Data{
           private  Translations translations;
          public Translations getTranslation()
          {
             return translations;
          }

          public void setTranslation(Translations translations)
           {
                  this.translations = translations;
           }
    }

    public class Translations
    {
        private  TranslatedText[] translatedText;
         public TranslatedText[] getArrayTranslatedText()
         {
             return translatedText;
         }

           public void setTranslatedText(TranslatedText[] translatedText)
           {
                  this.translatedText= translatedText;
           }
    }

    public class TranslatedText
    {
        private String translatedText;
        public String getTranslatedText()
        {
           return translatedText;
        }

        public void setTranslatedText(String translatedText)
        {
           this.translatedText = translatedText;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't you need some setters on those helper classes?  Nothing can set the `private String translatedText` without violating access control,   so there's no way `fromJSON` could set it in JVMs that have not opted-into reflection trampling all over access control.

Comment: @Mike Samuel shoot completely forgot about the Setters

Answer (score 5):

```
    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
    JsonObject jo = (JsonObject) parser.parse(data);
    JsonElement je = jo.get("some_array");

    //Parsing back the string as Array
    JsonArray ja = (JsonArray) parser.parse(o.get("some_array").getAsString());
    for (JsonElement jo : ja) {
    JsonObject j = (JsonObject) jo;
        // Your Code, Access json elements as j.get("some_element")
    }
```

A simple example to parse a JSON like this

> {
>   "some_array" : "[\"some_element\":1,\"some_more_element\":2]" ,
>   "some_other_element" : 3
>   }

Answer (score 4):

Firstly generate getter and setter using below parsing site

http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Now use Gson

```
GettetSetterClass object=new Gson().fromjson(jsonLine, GettetSetterClass.class);
```

Now use object to get values such as data,translationText

Answer (score 2):

You can use a JsonPath query to extract the value. And with [JsonSurfer](https://github.com/jsurfer/JsonSurfer) which is backed by Gson, your problem can be solved by simply two line of code!

```
    JsonSurfer jsonSurfer = JsonSurfer.gson();
    String result = jsonSurfer.collectOne(jsonLine, String.class, "$.data.translations[0].translatedText");
```

Answer (score 1):

One line code:

```
System.out.println(new Gson().fromJson(jsonLine,JsonObject.class).getAsJsonObject().get("data").getAsJsonObject().get("translations").getAsJsonArray().get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("translatedText").getAsString());
```