# Need to send json data from js to java

Tags: java, jquery, json, servlets

I have a JSON string in my javascript, I need to send this to a java class. Can I use a plain java class or is it necessary to use a servlet?

Also, How can I parse the JSON data?

My JSON data is of the following format:

```
 var details=   { "CustomerDetails": [{'name':'Amy','age':'23'},
{'name':'Amj','age':'25'},{'name':'Amg','age':'27'}]};
```

I send the json string like this:

```
  var jsonText = JSON.stringify(details);  

    $.post('ServletClass', jsonText);
```

**WEb.xml:**

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>ServletClass</servlet-name>
<display-name>ServletClass</display-name>
<servlet-class>java.files.ServletClass</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>ServletClass</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/ServletClass</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**On my servlet side:**
I try to do a system.out.println, but get nothing, is the transfer even happening properly

```
package XXXX;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.files.JSONObject;
import java.files.JSONSerializer;

public class ServletClass extends HttpServlet {
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

  }

  public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException, IOException {
      //          doGet(request, response);
      //JSONArray arrayObj = new JSONArray();
      JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonText);
      JSONArray the_
      json_array = jsonObj.getJSONArray("CustomerDetails");
      System.out.println("FINALLY HERE");



  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following change worked for me:
**fullpath=contextpath\servletname**

```
$.post(fullpath, {jsonText:jsonText}, function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you JSON is incorrect. Corrected JSON:

```
{ "CustomerDetails": [{'name':'Amy','age':'23'},{'name':'Amj','age':'25'},{'name':'Amg','age':'27'}]}
```

You should use AJAX to send data to the java class if you want it to be asynchronous. You will require a servlet to accept this request, that will parse this JSON and you can follow with the necessary processing on it. Look into [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) or [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) libraries to do JSON parsing.

Comment: is there an example you can guide me to... I am a newbie to js and JSON

Comment: For AJAX, you can use [jQuery library](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to communicate with your servlet. For using GSON, you can refer examples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490789/json-parsing-using-gson-for-java) and [here](http://www.javabeat.net/2012/04/parsing-json-using-java-and-gson-library/). [Here](http://veerasundar.com/blog/2008/12/implementing-ajax-in-java-web-application-using-jquery/) is an example of a client invoking AJAX call to a servlet.

Comment: As you try stuff, post your code in case you have questions or blocked on anything.

Comment: @HaranMurthy, I did not quite understand your question.

Comment: sorry hit enter by mistake..... edited the main question. I am not sure why my servlets post method isn't showing the sysout

Comment: @HaranMurthy, could you post your servlet class code where you try to read the variable from the request.

Comment: done... as you can see i do not see the print statement in the logs

Comment: In statement `JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonText);`, where is the `jsonText` coming from?

Comment: @gotuskar- yup haven't completed that part yet, but my question is there is no call made to the post method in the servlet. how does that happen.

Comment: You code wont compile because the variable `jsonText` is not declared. Try putting just the `System.out.println()` statements and remove everything else to make sure your servlet is being called. See the logs for possible run time exceptions.

Comment: No didnt work, I put the sysout in the first line by removing rest of the lines, the thing i dont get is how do i know the post method in the servlet is getting called and not the get

Comment: Because you are calling `$.post(...)`. Try hitting the URL from browser to invoke your servlet.

Comment: Thanks for your patience in helping me,  I tried to invoke it directly it threw a 404 error, does that mean my servlet mapping is incorrect?

Comment: I built the war and invoked the class file with the host post address and the full path

Comment: Thanks gotuskar... url was the issue, For some reason The url sent via ajax didn't generate properly. I updated the url and it works like a charm