# Gson Android and Async task

Tags: java, android

So i had a question not long ago about GSON now i was told to use something called AsyncTask

Even though the discribtion on how to use this is very brief [AsyncTask Doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

I managed to get it to work sort of.

This is my Async class:

```
public class JsonCollector extends AsyncTask<URL, integer, String> {
private String finalString;
public JsonCollector(){

}
public String test(){
    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL("http://api.heroesofnewerth.com/player_statistics/ranked/nickname/Hieratic/?token=0CZGH8ZI7UR8J2GN");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    String x = "";
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), "UTF-8"));
        for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
            System.out.println(line);
            x = line;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally{
        if (reader !=null) try{reader.close();} catch (IOException ignore) {
        }{}
    }
    this.finalString = x;
    return x;
}
@Override
protected String doInBackground(URL... params) {
    JsonElement root = new JsonParser().parse(test());

    finalString = root.getAsJsonObject().get("rnk_wins").toString();
    return "";
}
public String getFinalString(){
    return finalString;
}
```

}

Now this works fine exepect im getting a GSON error:

```
  05-15 19:51:05.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1832): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
05-15 19:51:05.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1832): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
05-15 19:51:05.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1832):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
05-15 19:51:05.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1832):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
05-15 19:51:05.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1832):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
05-15 19:51:05.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1832):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
05-15 19:51:05.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1832):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
05-15 19:51:05.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1832):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
05-15 19:51:05.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1832):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
05-15 19:51:05.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1832):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-15 19:51:05.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1832): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.gson.JsonParser
05-15 19:51:05.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1832):     at logic.JsonCollector.doInBackground(JsonCollector.java:47)
05-15 19:51:05.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1832):     at logic.JsonCollector.doInBackground(JsonCollector.java:1)
05-15 19:51:05.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1832):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
05-15 19:51:05.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1832):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
05-15 19:51:05.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1832):     ... 4 more
```

Please do note that i have added the lib to my project:

[image]

Can anyone tell me why im getting the class not found execption?

Comment: do you have the gson jar file in your \libs folder?

Comment: @EmilAdz i have them under my Referenced Libraries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that you have it under the `Referenced Libraries` library is your problem.

what you need to do is to create a `\libs` in your project folder and place your jar file there.

this will result in placing this library under the `Android Dependecies` folder in your project (you might need to clear your project/close and reopen Eclipse).

**UPDATE:**

This screen shot should explain, where you should put your used `.jar` file for your project.

[image]

Comment: so what your saying is i should create a folder called libs and enter the jars within those

Comment: you saved me alot of trouble THANK YOU so much btw is the way im handling the Gson correctly? i mean with the Async

Comment: If my answer helped you, you should upvote/accept it. regarding the gson handling, it looks right, take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490789/json-parsing-using-gson-for-java