# How to parse this kind of json String using Gson?

Tags: java, android, json

```
{
    "status": "Success",
    "message": "Contents retrieved successfully",
    "name": {
        "1": "God",
        "2": "Goat"
    },
    "sites": {
        "1": "google",
        "2": "yahoo",
        "3": "bing"
    },
    "places": [
        "UK",
        "AU",
        "US"
    ],
    "images": {
        "1": {
            "1x": "http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-PPrUA_pcNyI/Udtx6v7MlvI/AAAAAAAADZA/6X2Qu-FcHtA/s320/Android+JSON+stream+data+parsing+example+using+Gson.png",
            "2x": "http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-PPrUA_pcNyI/Udtx6v7MlvI/AAAAAAAADZA/6X2Qu-FcHtA/s320/Android+JSON+stream+data+parsing+example+using+Gson.png"
        },
        "2": {
            "1x": "http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-PPrUA_pcNyI/Udtx6v7MlvI/AAAAAAAADZA/6X2Qu-FcHtA/s320/Android+JSON+stream+data+parsing+example+using+Gson.png",
            "2x": "http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-PPrUA_pcNyI/Udtx6v7MlvI/AAAAAAAADZA/6X2Qu-FcHtA/s320/Android+JSON+stream+data+parsing+example+using+Gson.png"
        },
        "3": {
            "1x": "http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-PPrUA_pcNyI/Udtx6v7MlvI/AAAAAAAADZA/6X2Qu-FcHtA/s320/Android+JSON+stream+data+parsing+example+using+Gson.png",
            "2x": "http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-PPrUA_pcNyI/Udtx6v7MlvI/AAAAAAAADZA/6X2Qu-FcHtA/s320/Android+JSON+stream+data+parsing+example+using+Gson.png"
        }
    }
}
```

My Class

import java.util.Map;

```
public class Data {

    String status;
    String message;
    Map<String, String> name;
    Map<String, String> Sites;
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Data [status=" + status + ", message=" + message
                + ", name=" + name + ", Sites=" + Sites
                + "]";
    }


}
```

this class returns null value for the while retrieving sites and names

Comment: Just follow the steps of these tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: it needs to be parsed wih gson

Comment: @Tony Stark-Just see this link tell me it is useful or not http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490789/json-parsing-using-gson-for-java

Comment: _sites_ and _name_ are `Map` on your `Data` class, whereas they are represented by `JSONObject` for gson. I think you need to create a customized deserializer, as explained here : https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Writing-a-Deserializer

Comment: Where do you get this JSON from? or is it your own?

Comment: @Tony Stark-Just see this link       http://rishabhsays.wordpress.com/2011/02/24/parsing-list-of-json-objects-with-gson/

Comment: you have any error in this JSON during parse.

Comment: no friends it is loading well but null

Answer (score 1):

name and sites are JSONObjects no Arrays. Any Object in a JSON have to deserialised in a class using GSON.

So try this,

```
public class MyJson {
    String status;
    String message;

    Sites sites;
    List<String> places;
}

public class Sites {
    String 1;
    String 2;
    String 3;
}
```

and so on for every Object. For Arrays you can use List / Map.

To use it make a call like this:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
MyJson myJson = gson.fromJson(yourJsonString, MyJson.class);
```

Comment: this could work (particularly after removing the brackets at the classes definition), but it's not flexible enough as it seems that the JSON object can have an arbitrary number of elements for the keys `name`, `sites`, `places` and `images` (and for the contents of the latter too)

Comment: @AlonsoDominguez Now I know what you mean with "removing the brackets..". Thx for the edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject object = (JsonObject)parser.parse(yourString);

for (Map.Entry<String,JsonElement> entry : object.entrySet()) {
    JsonArray array = entry.getValue().getAsJsonArray();
    for (JsonElement elementJSON : array) {
        [...]
    }
}
```