# How to access nested elements from a JSON using Java (Bing-Search-API)

Tags: java, json, gson, bing-api

I have [this](https://gist.github.com/lumalav/6222895#file-myjson) JSON that I retrieved using Bing-Search-API. Now, I'm not sure how to access the nested elements using GSON. I already made the [source files](https://gist.github.com/lumalav/6222895) for the JSON Structure Data.

If I do this:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();

JsonArray Jarray = parser.parse(jsonText).getAsJsonArray();
```

It is going to throw me that is not a `JsonArray`, so If I change it to `JsonObject`, how can I retrieve the `String MediaUrl` from [Results.java](https://gist.github.com/lumalav/6222895#file-results-java)?

Thank you

Comment: Have you looked at this [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490789/json-parsing-using-gson-for-java)?

Comment: Didn't work :( this line: jobject = jobject.getAsJsonObject("data"); doesn't accept a String for me. Is that example using gson as well?

Comment: Can you upload the GIST of your code

Comment: [Sure](https://gist.github.com/lumalav/6222895#file-jsonparser2-java)

Comment: In your Gist on Line 5 you need these statement `jobject = jobject.getAsJsonObject("d");`. Having said that I would prefer to use @Katona's version

Comment: Thanks, but yes; that is what I tried. But it doesn't accept the String "d" as an input. That is why I am not sure if they are using Gson on their problems.

Comment: Curious what version of GSON are you using?

Comment: it is version 2.2.4.jar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the javadoc of [Gson](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/index.html) class:

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Response response = gson.fromJson(jsonText, Response.class);
    Results firstResult = response.getD().getResults().get(0);
    System.out.println(firstResult.getMediaUrl());
```

So you don't need to use the `JsonParser` directly.

Your java classes have to be modified a little bit for this to work:

- the type of `results` field in `D.java` has to be `List<Results>` so that `Gson` can find out the class of objects to populate with.
- the naming of attributes/fields is inconsistent, some starts with lower case, others with uppercase. Make sure they are the same in the java classes and in the json string (considering case sensitivity). This issue might be addressed with using the appropriate [FieldNamingStrategy](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/index.html?com/google/gson/FieldNamingStrategy.html) for serialization/deserialization.

Comment: Thank you, but it's returning null. I am using this as you mentioned: Gson gson = new Gson(); 
 Results res = gson.fromJson(jsonText, Results.class);
 System.out.println( res.getMediaUrl());

Comment: Could you take a look to my gist please?

Comment: [This is what I tried](https://gist.github.com/lumalav/6222895#file-jsonparser-java)

Comment: @LuisLavieri updated my answer, your "root element" is `Response`, so that's what you have to specify at `gson.fromJson(...)`

Comment: Thanks, but how can I access MediaUrl? when I try to populate a List from "response.getD().getResults()" it throws me an IllegalException

Comment: @LuisLavieri I updated my answer, please note that I had to modify your java classes to get it work, how did you get them?

Comment: Now it is giving me Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to BingSearchExample.Results and the option that is giving me is adding a cast to Results which does not work or change result type. :(

Comment: I'm sorry, I was trying to follow your example. Did you change jsonParser2.java? that one throws me a NPE

Comment: @LuisLavieri use the code snippet in my answer for deserialization, that is use `Gson` class instead of `JsonParser`

Comment: Hi, sorry for bothering you again. But now I was trying to get MediaUrl from Thumbnail.java. I tried changing Result.java so it could return a List<Thumbnail>, and then in my code I tried in a loop thumbnails[i] = response.getD().getResults().thumbnail.get(i); , but, it is not working. What is happening?

Comment: @LuisLavieri continuing the example in the answer: `firstResult.getThumbnail().getMediaUrl()`