# Android: parse the JSON file in the raw folder with gson?

Tags: android, json, gson

I am trying to parse JSON file"ssid-number" in the raw folder with GSON. The parse_SSID method parses the JSON file and finds the mapping for the passed SSID  string. I am getting at the momenat this error:`The method getWifiList() is undefined for the type WifiJSON` at this line `List<WifiJSON> wifijson = obj.getWifiList();`. Is my approach correct?

JSON file:

```js
{
    "data": [
        {
            "ssid": "KD Privat",
            "route_number": 1
        },
        {
            "ssid": "KD WLAN Hotspot",
            "route_number": 4
        },
        {
            "ssid": "FR WLAN",
            "route_number": 6
        }
    ]
}
```

parse_SSID method in the MainActivity:

```js
        private int parse_SSID(String ssid) {

             InputStream raw =  getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.ssid_number);
             Reader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(raw));
             Gson gson = new Gson();            
            WifiJSON obj = gson.fromJson(rd, WifiJSON.class);
            // Now iterate through the list
            List<WifiJSON> wifijson = obj.getWifiList(); //here is my error.
            Iterator iterator = wifijson.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                WifiJSON wifielement = (WifiJSON) iterator.next();
                System.out.println(wifielement.getSsid() + "----"
                        + wifielement.getRoute_number());
            }

        }
```

WifiJSON class:

```js
public class WifiJSON {
    private String ssid;
    private int route_number;

    public WifiJSON(String ssid, int route_number) {
        this.ssid = ssid;
        this.route_number = route_number;

    }

    private String getSsid() {
        return ssid;
    }

    private void setSsid(String ssid) {
        this.ssid = ssid;
    }

    private int getRoute_number() {
        return route_number;
    }

    private void setRoute_number(int route_number) {
        this.route_number = route_number;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "WifiJSON [ssid=" + ssid + ", route_number=" + route_number
                + "]";
    }



}
```

WiFiJSONList class:

```js
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class WiFiJSONList {
    private ArrayList<WifiJSON> data;

    public ArrayList<WifiJSON> getWifiList() {
        return data;
    }
    public void setWifiList(ArrayList<WifiJSON> wifiList) {
        this.data = wifiList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just make JSONObject?

Comment: if it works then it is ok but I used gson because i have read it is the easiest approach. I will add another  SSID and route_number About 400 pairs to the JSON file

Comment: Reread [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29633998/2835243) answer you got earlier. `getWifiList` is a getter in the `WiFiJSONList` class. Yet, you call it on a `WifiJSON` object.

Comment: Please see this, I used it, so far so good.
https://gist.github.com/dominicthomas/ec1ce6d98dc81f6db614

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
WifiJSON obj = gson.fromJson(rd, WifiJSON.class);
```

should be

```
WiFiJSONList obj = gson.fromJson(rd, WiFiJSONList.class);
```

Comment: You mean `WiFiJSONList obj = gson.fromJson(rd, WiFiJSONList.class);` ?

Comment: where have I to place the "ssid" parameter in the emthod to get  the right route-number? parse_SSID(String ssid)