# Custom mapping with GSon

Tags: android, json, gson

Is there any way to mapping nested json object into single Java class?
for example, I have this json string:

```
{
  "order_id": 104,
  "order_details" : [
    {
      "name": "Product#1",
      "price": {
        "usd": 12.95
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to map with this class:

```
public class Order{
   Int id; // rename
   String name; //map with order_details.name
   float price; //map with order_details.price.usd
}
```

*UPDATE:
Sorry for unclear question. I am developer for both Objective-C and Java. When I work with JSONModel in ObjC, It's easy to config the mapping like this: https://github.com/icanzilb/JSONModel#key-mapping

I hate to parse JSON manually using `getJSONObject()`, `getString()`, ... I am finding a way to configure for automatically parsing with `Gson` for Java.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON parsing using Gson for java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490789/json-parsing-using-gson-for-java)

Comment: What did you try ? There are lot of examples on SO or google...

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse. You can do it by using **GSON** library. You need to crate 2 pojo and the one which is at outside can have custom model.

Answer (score 0):

You can try modify your model like this:

```
public class Order {

    int id; // rename
    String name; //map with order_details.name
    float price; //map with order_details.price.usd

    public void parce(String json) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
            id = jsonObject.getInt("order_id");
            name = jsonObject.getJSONArray("order_details").getJSONObject(0).getString("name");
            price = (float) jsonObject.getJSONArray("order_details").getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("price").getDouble("usd");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Example to using this code:

```
Order order = new Order();
order.parce("{\"order_id\":104,\"order_details\":[{\"name\":\"Product#1\",\"price\":{\"usd\":12.95}}]}");
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: your solution seems doesn't use Gson for Java?