# Gson, parse object of arrays using retrofit

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit

I have this server response:

```
{ "result" : true , "content" : {
    "files" : [],
    "filesNames" : [],
    "folders" : []
    }
}
```

How can i create a gson object to make retrofit adapt that response? Because this doesn't seem to work(i only need files and folders):

```
public class GetUserFilesAnswer {

    public boolean result;
    public List<Integer> files;
    public List<String> folders;


}

client.getUserFiles(email, token, path, new Callback<GetUserFilesAnswer>() {
        @Override
        public void success(GetUserFilesAnswer getUserFilesAnswer, Response response) {
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON parsing using Gson for java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490789/json-parsing-using-gson-for-java)

Answer (score 1):

Try this model:

```
public class GetUserFilesAnswer {

    public static class Content {
       public List<Integer> files;
       public List<String> folders;
    }

    public boolean result;
    public Content content;

}
```