# Accessing value with same named parent

Tags: java, json, jenkins, gson

Here I have some JSON generated by Jenkins, I would like to access the value `Started by user XXX` in the below JSON with GSON.

Although as you can see there are two `causes` in the `actions` array. Although sometimes there is only one (In which case just return that one).

**Question:** How can I access the first `causes` only OR even better conjoin them both so I could access it like `Started by user XXX - Rebuilds build #2`

I cannot change the JSON unfortunately.

Edit* I understand the title is probably not the best although I cannot think of another way of phrasing it so if anyone can think of a better one I would be much obliged.

```
{
  "jobs" : [
    {
      "name" : "Test Build",
      "url" : "URL",
      "lastBuild" : {
        "actions" : [
          {
            "causes" : [
              {
                "shortDescription" : "Started by user XXX"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "causes" : [
              {
                "shortDescription" : "Rebuilds build #2"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "parameters" : [
              {
                "name" : "ENVIRONMENT",
                "value" : "PROD"
              },
              {
                "name" : "RELEASE"
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "building" : false,
        "duration" : 126580,
        "estimatedDuration" : 74509,
        "number" : 3,
        "timestamp" : 1445261252000,
        "url" : "URL",
        "builtOn" : "D-slave"
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with expression below. 0 index will give you first element.

```
jobs[0].lastBuild.actions[0].causes
```

This will give you

```
[
   [
      {
         "shortDescription":"Started by user XXX"
      }
   ]
]
```

Change the expression wherever necessary.

Java code for all classes below - based on your json format.

So you need something like jenkinjobs.jobs(0).getActions(0).

```
    public class Jenkinjobs
    {
        private Jobs[] jobs;

        public Jobs[] getJobs ()
        {
            return jobs;
        }

        public void setJobs (Jobs[] jobs)
        {
            this.jobs = jobs;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            return "ClassPojo [jobs = "+jobs+"]";
        }
    }


public class Jobs
{
    private LastBuild lastBuild;

    private String name;

    private String url;

    public LastBuild getLastBuild ()
    {
        return lastBuild;
    }

    public void setLastBuild (LastBuild lastBuild)
    {
        this.lastBuild = lastBuild;
    }

    public String getName ()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName (String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getUrl ()
    {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl (String url)
    {
        this.url = url;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [lastBuild = "+lastBuild+", name = "+name+", url = "+url+"]";
    }
}


public class LastBuild
{
    private String timestamp;

    private String estimatedDuration;

    private String duration;

    private String building;

    private String number;

    private String builtOn;

    private String url;

    private Actions[] actions;

    public String getTimestamp ()
    {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp (String timestamp)
    {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public String getEstimatedDuration ()
    {
        return estimatedDuration;
    }

    public void setEstimatedDuration (String estimatedDuration)
    {
        this.estimatedDuration = estimatedDuration;
    }

    public String getDuration ()
    {
        return duration;
    }

    public void setDuration (String duration)
    {
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public String getBuilding ()
    {
        return building;
    }

    public void setBuilding (String building)
    {
        this.building = building;
    }

    public String getNumber ()
    {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber (String number)
    {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getBuiltOn ()
    {
        return builtOn;
    }

    public void setBuiltOn (String builtOn)
    {
        this.builtOn = builtOn;
    }

    public String getUrl ()
    {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl (String url)
    {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public Actions[] getActions ()
    {
        return actions;
    }

    public void setActions (Actions[] actions)
    {
        this.actions = actions;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [timestamp = "+timestamp+", estimatedDuration = "+estimatedDuration+", duration = "+duration+", building = "+building+", number = "+number+", builtOn = "+builtOn+", url = "+url+", actions = "+actions+"]";
    }
}

public class Parameters
{
    private String name;

    private String value;

    public String getName ()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName (String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getValue ()
    {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue (String value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [name = "+name+", value = "+value+"]";
    }
}



public class Actions
{
    private Causes[] causes;

    public Causes[] getCauses ()
    {
        return causes;
    }

    public void setCauses (Causes[] causes)
    {
        this.causes = causes;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [causes = "+causes+"]";
    }
}



public class Causes
{
    private String shortDescription;

    public String getShortDescription ()
    {
        return shortDescription;
    }

    public void setShortDescription (String shortDescription)
    {
        this.shortDescription = shortDescription;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [shortDescription = "+shortDescription+"]";
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry how is this supposed to be used with GSON?

Comment: Well for that you need to write code and get the data for a given pojo or object. Try reading these links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490789/json-parsing-using-gson-for-java and http://www.javacreed.com/simple-gson-example/ to get started. At the end of day its JSONArray, JSONObject or JSONElement.

Comment: Yeah it's the GSON part I need help with. How would I set up the class to be able to accept both or just the first `causes`

Comment: Ah I see you can set it with class[] that's brilliant thank you!