# Light weight jar to achieve both JSON parsing & object mapping

Tags: java, json, gson

**Task 1**

json1:

```
[
  {
    "name": "test1",
    "details": {
      "url": "url1"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "test2",
    "details": {
      "url": "url2"
    }
  }
]
```

I need to parse this JSON & fetch **url** field.

**Task 2**

json2:

```
{
  "id": 1234,
  "name": "Devender Yadav",
  "location": "Noida"
}
```

I need to map this JSON to below mentioned java object.

```
public class UserDetail {

    private String name;

    private String location;

    //getters setters
}
```

I am using **`gson`**(version 2.5) for object mapping & **`json`**(version 20151123) for parsing.

I don't want to use two jars for such simple task.

How can I achieve this using 1 jar (*any light weight jar*) ?

Comment: And the reason you don't want to have two jar files is ....

Comment: @Thilo I think it can be done using 1 jar. Don't you?

Comment: Well, for starters, you could do JSON parsing with GSON as well. Why do you use another library for that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490789/json-parsing-using-gson-for-java?rq=1

Comment: @Thilo yes both are achieved using gson. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked **`gson`** & found both Parsing & Object Mapping are achiveved using it.

**Parsing :**

```
JsonArray jArray = new JsonParser().parse(json1).getAsJsonArray();

for (int j = 0; j < jArray.size(); j++) {
    JsonObject jObject = jArray.get(j).getAsJsonObject();
    String url = jObject.getAsJsonObject("details").get("url").getAsString();
 }
```

**Object Mapping :**

```
JsonObject jObject = new JsonParser().parse(json2).getAsJsonObject();
Gson gson = new Gson();
UserDetail userDetail = gson.fromJson(jObject.toString(), UserDetail.class);
```