# How to parse JSON array with single element without any object in Retrofit?

Tags: android, json, retrofit, gson

I am using Retrofit which uses  GSON for parsing.The server will check the parameter i am sending and returns two responses Accordingly.
If the parameter is valid i am getting the following response

```
[
  true
]
```

If it is not valid then i get response as,

```
   [
      "Sorry, <em class=\"placeholder\">names@gmail.inp</em> is not recognized as a user name or an e-mail address."
    ]
```

This is the call method i am using.

@Override

```
public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    Log.d("Response ", ""+response);


}
```

here response.body giving me as null. But there is a response.which is viewable in OKHttp Log.

Comment: Make that parameter as `Object`. After parsing check if the parsed Object `instanceof` Boolean or String.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
 JSONArray jArray=new JSONArray(yourString);

 String str=jArray.getString(0);;
 if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("true")
 {
      //your code
 }else
 {
 }
```

Comment: i am not getting as jsonob.

Comment: i am not even getting as string

Comment: the value i am getting response.body() is null in my activity.But there is a response which we can see inD/OkHttp:   ["Sorry, <em class=\"placeholder\">gjgh@gmail.com</em> is not recognized as a user name or an e-mail address."]

Comment: first convert it into string than try it .

Comment: Thats what i am trying !! Thats actually my question

Comment: please first make your Question Clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONArray jarray = new JSONObject(jsonString);
for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
      String string = jarray.getString(i);
      log.e("String",string);
}
```

that's working great. Please try this.

Comment: I am not even getting JSONObject

Comment: but you can get responce in onsuccess method of retrofit.
In this on siccess method you can parsing directly.

Comment: i am getting null as response.body()

Comment: first you check your url.
if url is right check your retrofit code.

Comment: public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {

        String sresponce = response.body();

    }

Comment: and then parsing sresponce normally.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JsonParser` provided by **Gson**. It will parse the json input to dynamic JsonElement.

Look at [MByD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5490987/1129332) example:

```
 public String parse(String jsonLine) {
    JsonElement jelement = new JsonParser().parse(jsonLine);
    JsonObject  jobject = jelement.getAsJsonObject();
    jobject = jobject.getAsJsonObject("data");
    JsonArray jarray = jobject.getAsJsonArray("translations");
    jobject = jarray.get(0).getAsJsonObject();
    String result = jobject.get("translatedText").toString();
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

since the server return diffrent codes

can you try

```
Call<Void>
```

and check the response code
this might work for now until you know what is wrong void will not parse any thing so it shouldn't cause a crash

///////

did you try

```
Call<ArrayList<String>>
```

also are you sure the server returns 200 in both cases ?

Comment: I tried this one first.that time i got null pointer exception. the server returns 200  and 406 respectively  different in two cases.

Comment: try  Call<Void>  and tell me how did it go