# javax.json objects have same methods, but they're not implementations of a common interface. How to cast?

Tags: java, json

I'm dealing with the strange `javax.json` library. So here's the problem:

I need to cast an `Object` of type `JsonValue` to either `JsonObject` or `JsonArray` so I can call the methods `getJsonObject` and `getJsonArray` of it. Both `JsonArray` and `JsonObject` have the same method names with the same functionalities but they're not implemented methods, they are methods defined on each of them! See: [JsonObject](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html), [JsonArray](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonArray.html).

The obvious solution would be to verify the type and then cast depending on the verified type, like this:

```
            if (current.getValueType().equals(JsonValue.ValueType.OBJECT)) {
                current = ((JsonObject) current).getJsonObject(node);
            } else if (current.getValueType().equals(JsonValue.ValueType.ARRAY)) {
                current = ((JsonArray) current).getJsonObject(node);
            }
```

but it'd require too many repetitions on my code. So I ask:

1) If both `JsonObject` and `JsonArray` have the same methods, why they're not implementations of some interface?

2) Is there a more elegant way to cast the object to `JsonObject` or `JsonArray` at the same time by using some trick? Do you know any way to make this situation better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the 2 methods on the 2 different objects have the same name, their signatures are in fact different.  [`JsonObject#getJsonObject(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html#getJsonObject-java.lang.String-) accepts a `String` key identifying the value to pull from a JSON object of key-value pairs.  [`JsonArray#getJsonObject(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonArray.html#getJsonObject-int-) accepts an `int` index identifying which element to pull the value from in a JSON array.

In this case, there is no appropriate common interface that the 2 classes can share.  Your code will have to know whether to inspect a JSON object or a JSON array and cast accordingly.

Since the 2 methods in question do not have the same signature, there are not other alternatives for calling them in a "common way".  You could potentially use reflection, but this risks making the code more confusing.  For example, Apache Commons includes [`MethodUtils#invokeMethod`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/reflect/MethodUtils.html#invokeMethod-java.lang.Object-boolean-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-).  You could potentially use that to invoke any method named "getJsonObject", accepting any kind of object (either `String` or `int`).  Although using this would make it "common code" across both cases, it's potentially confusing for people reading the code later.  They'd have to keep track of the fact that this is using reflection, and that the passed argument might be either `String` or `int`, and that it really all works out thanks to it being either a JSON object or array.  Instead, I would favor just doing the downcast in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Chris is right, Your code will have to know whether to inspect a JSON object or a JSON array and cast accordingly. However, if you are ok with adding an external library, I would recommend [gson](https://github.com/google/gson) for parsing Json 
This library has [JsonElement](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/JsonElement.html) class which should fit good in your case. look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5490987/2299040) to see how it works