# Request data from mysql server using Volley in Android studio

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio, android-volley

This is what I have tried:
The database is in my localhost and I am using my own IP.

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    try{
                    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);

                        for (int x = 0; x<array.length();x++){

                            JSONObject ob = array.getJSONObject(x);

                            Alumnos list = new Alumnos();
                            list.setUsername(ob.getString("username"));
                            list.setJob(ob.getString("job"));
                            list.setAge(ob.getInt("age"));

                            alumnos.add(list);

                        }

                        updateRecycler(alumnos);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }


            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.i("Error: ", error.toString());
        }
    }

    );
    queue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

I try to show my results in a Recycler view but I get the next error:

```
10-03 21:41:28.033 10077-10077/? W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value {"result":[{"userid":"1","username":"Luis","job":"developer","age":"23"},{"userid":"2","username":"Alejandro","job":"agronomo","age":"24"},{"userid":"3","username":"Gabriel","job":"Redes","age":"24"}]} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

I think I might be missing something veri obvious because I get the Array in the Logcat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You are receiving a JSONObject (`{}`)
2. Your data is inside a JSONArray (`[]`)  i.e. `result` so use

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
JSONArray array = obj.getJSONArray("result");
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Pavneet_Singh for your help, this solved my issue. Just One question. Is there any way to avoid parsing the result and get the data directly from the String (result)

Comment: Yes, You can use parsers like GSON, Jackson etc like https://stackoverflow.com/a/15753925/4936904

Comment: I am glad that I could help, happy coding!