# How to Parse json response using Gson Library in android?

Tags: android, json, gson

I have api its response like this:

```
{
"0": "_serialize",
"1": [
    "login"
],
"users": {
    "token": "aaaaa",
    "message": "login successful."
    }
  }
```

How can I parse this in android using Gson ?

Comment: You need to use it by using _Iterator_.

Comment: can you give me example?

Comment: i think it can be used the model class, but using dynamic keys are not ideal for json format, u can replace "0", "1" by constant  key

Comment: Use [this link](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) here paste your raw JSON, select GSON in Annotation Style and get the relevant POJO classes on the click of the preview.

Comment: use @AseemSharma link to generate model class, but i will cause problem if "0" and "1" are not constant keys

Comment: @kubersingh that should be mentioned at first, I cannot assume it not to be a constant.

Comment: @AseemSharma, exactly, I am not with the problem, I m just supporting your words, just telling Dharmi that it may cause the problem if they are not constant keys

Comment: JSON should have pre-defined set of keys to be parsed without probem. If your JSON may have other keys than 0 and 1, then it is not well-structured for parsing, and it is the server-side which should be changer to return you the JSONArray instead of object with 0,1,2,3,4,... keys.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON parsing using Gson for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490789/json-parsing-using-gson-for-java)

Comment: @Dharmi-Patel Feel free to accept and vote the correct answer if it helped you out.

Answer (score 3):

Create a pojo of your Json. you can do so with many resources available online like [this](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) or [this](http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/).

Now use below format.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
MyPojo myPojo = new MyPojo();
Type collectionType = new TypeToken<MyPojo>() {
                    }.getType();
myPojo = gson.fromJson(responseJson,
                            collectionType);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

First of all make **model** classes from your **json** using tools like [this one](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/). Just copy your json and get the objects.

Let's suppose you call the class `Model`

Then use this `code` to get **object** from your json.

```
String json = "that-json";
Model m = gson.fromJson(json, Model.class);
```

More on [Gson's guides](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md).

Answer (score 1):

Generate the Model class from the response

```
    public void onResponse(String response) {   
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

        YourModelClass objModel = gson.fromJson(jsonObject.getJSONObject("data").toString(), YourModelClass.class);

 } catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use gson and map your response to Java Model class.

This will be your model class ->

User.java Model class.

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.ToStringBuilder;

public class Users implements Serializable
{

    @SerializedName("token")
    @Expose
    private String token;
    @SerializedName("message")
    @Expose
    private String message;
    private final static long serialVersionUID = 3387741697269012981L;

    /**
     * No args constructor for use in serialization
     * 
     */
    public Users() {
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param message
     * @param token
     */
    public Users(String token, String message) {
        super();
        this.token = token;
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public void setToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }

    public Users withToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
        return this;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public Users withMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new ToStringBuilder(this).append("token", token).append("message", message).toString();
    }

}
```

this is your root/parent class, from where parsing starts.

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.ToStringBuilder;

public class Root implements Serializable
{

    @SerializedName("0")
    @Expose
    private String _0;
    @SerializedName("1")
    @Expose
    private List<String> _1 = null;
    @SerializedName("users")
    @Expose
    private Users users;
    private final static long serialVersionUID = 5880229946098431789L;

    /**
     * No args constructor for use in serialization
     * 
     */
    public Example() {
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param users
     * @param _0
     * @param _1
     */
    public Example(String _0, List<String> _1, Users users) {
        super();
        this._0 = _0;
        this._1 = _1;
        this.users = users;
    }

    public String get0() {
        return _0;
    }

    public void set0(String _0) {
        this._0 = _0;
    }

    public Example with0(String _0) {
        this._0 = _0;
        return this;
    }

    public List<String> get1() {
        return _1;
    }

    public void set1(List<String> _1) {
        this._1 = _1;
    }

    public Example with1(List<String> _1) {
        this._1 = _1;
        return this;
    }

    public Users getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(Users users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    public Example withUsers(Users users) {
        this.users = users;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new ToStringBuilder(this).append("_0", _0).append("_1", _1).append("users", users).toString();
    }

}
```

now at the code where you receive Json map json to this root/parent class from where parsing starts.

```
Root root = new Gson().fromJson(/*put your json response variable here*/, Root.class);
```

and use root object to fetch/set any data via public get methods.