# How to parse a JSON using GSON, to get JSONObject where it is not parsed as desired for a bad JSON?

Tags: android, json, gson

The question is that when I am parsing the following **JSON** using **GSON** library, I am getting **GSON** class in the form of **POJO**, where every key and value has a getter and setter.

See the example of such bad **JSON** below, as not parsed correctly by **GSON** library

Now that is not the format I require. Instead, I want a hashmap object in return *(Library can return ArrayList then why not TreeHashMap ?)*. For me, this part of JSON is not parsed by GSON as I desire.

My question is whether I should ask my back-end team to reformat the **JSON** as in second **JSON** below, or to try to use **GSON** library as is but extract that `JSONObject` programmatically from **JSON** where the keys are dynamic in nature, and it is uncertain whether there are a couple of such keys there or thousands of them in the **JSON** that is returned.

See the example of the *good* **JSON** format below, converted from the *bad* JSON I have provided as it can be easily parsed by **GSON** to the format I desire

For this, either I have to explain a rule to my back-end team:

**RULE:**

The keys should not be dynamic in nature. If in case the keys are dynamic, a list of searchable keys should also be defined in the same **JSON** or separate **MODEL JSON** that should be requested in a call before this **JSON** is parsed (in a separate Web-Service API response).

**Example of bad JSON:**

```
{"Grocery": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Kirana Store",
        "parent_id": 1,
        "category_image": "",
        "category_type": "product",
        "position": 0,
        "front_status": 0,
        "slug_url": "daal-pulses",
        "created_at": "2016-06-27 06:44:59",
        "updated_at": "2018-02-13 04:55:33"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Departmental Store",
        "parent_id": 1,
        "category_image": "",
        "category_type": "product",
        "position": 0,
        "front_status": 0,
        "slug_url": "dry-fruits",
        "created_at": "2016-06-27 06:45:12",
        "updated_at": "2018-02-13 04:56:01"
      }
    ]}
```

and there may be thousands of dynamic keys like "`Grocery`" say like "`Stationary`", "`Hosiery`", "`Medicines`", or so... as categories of products. *GSON will make getters for each such dynamic key.*

**Should be corrected and returned by web-service API as:**

```
{

  "Products": [

    {

      "parent_category": "Grocery",

      "items": [

        {

          "id": 2,

          "name": "Kirana Store",

          "parent_id": 1,

          "category_image": "",

          "category_type": "product",

          "position": 0,

          "front_status": 0,

          "slug_url": "daal-pulses",

          "created_at": "2016-06-27 06:44:59",

          "updated_at": "2018-02-13 04:55:33"

        },

        {

          "id": 3,

          "name": "Departmental Store",

          "parent_id": 1,

          "category_image": "",

          "category_type": "product",

          "position": 0,

          "front_status": 0,

          "slug_url": "dry-fruits",

          "created_at": "2016-06-27 06:45:12",

          "updated_at": "2018-02-13 04:56:01"

        }

      ]

    }

  ]

}
```

Where there can be thousands of categories as `Grocery` as described above, and getters for such keys can not be computed at run time. But if these keys are converted to values, represented by a common key each, as in the correction above, then having a common getter for that key "`parent_category`" makes sense. Now, this is the **JSON** that **GSON** can parse to my desired output. But the thing is that our back end team do not co-operate to change anything, because there is a re-work here. If I switch to traditional parsing, there will be a huge re-work at my end as well.

OR I have to find out a way where I can extract the `JSONObject` from the **JSON** using **GSON** so that I can parse it manually.

Hence I need something to save time that will go in this re-work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting JSONObject that is not parsed by GSON as desired:

[Getting JSONObject from JSON where it is not parsable by GSON](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18443395/787399):

Use `keySet()` of `JSONObject` to get the keys from `JSON`, as Set collection. Iterating through the keys in the Set, I am obtaining corresponding values, in the current `JSON` section.

Please see the example:

[Java Code Examples for org.json.JSONObject.keySet()](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=org.json.JSONObject&method=keySet)

Now if `GSON` can not parse such kind of `JSON` formats, where it gives getters and setters for each key and if the developer has to parse `JSON` manually, then still there is a chance of saving time, using this solution. But till `GSON` make amendments as you suggest it should, you have to live with this solution.

**What should I have done if I were in GSON development team?:**

There should have been another kind of annotation where instead of getting getters and setters, one should be able to demand from the `GSON` library to return `key-value` pairs in the form of `hash-map` or `array-list` of POJO in the output. This at present is not there.

Happy Coding ;-)

Comment: @Vivek Mishra I don't get you, There is an answer there how to get a JSON Object from a GSON, right? where you were not getting desired output from GSON library, as it seldom returns POJO for such JSONObject where the keys are dynamic in nature. Please answer for me.

Comment: And instead of relying too much on Gson to do the parsing, you can always parse it manually in any data structure you want.

Comment: @Vivek Mishra, sure Sir, but In my case I had used GSON, and now I had to save my time because lots of time would go in rework. The schedule to finish the project did not allowed me. GSON definitely saves a lot of time.

Comment: I am not against your post at all. I am just saying to rephrase your answer to remove things like "What is the use of this library?". This is a question in itself. So that's what I am saying to rephrase it.

Comment: I mean to say it is not useful for me as I haven't faced this problem but will be useful for someone who faces this issue.

Comment: @Vivek Mishra OK, so I wish you best of luck instead. Probably you get a team always that co-operates with you to never let you in this kind of situation I am facing.