# gson parse items from comma-separated-value string within a json value

Tags: java, json, csv, gson

I am parsing a `json` string using `gson`. It is similar to this:

```
{
    "ACode": "aa",
    "RCode": "rr",
    "Errors": "e1,e2,e3"
}
```

I think that the errors should have been a proper `json` array, but I don't have control of that.

I want to get the errors into an array or collection in `java`. This is easy enough using `String.split` with comma as separator. However I am new to `gson` and I don't know if I would be ignoring functionality that it provides to parse a comma separated string.

Does anyone know whether `gson` can handle this automatically?

Comment: I don't know of any functionality in gson to handle it automatically, but the best way to go about it would probably be to write a custom deserializer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6096940/how-do-i-write-a-custom-json-deserializer-for-gson

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get the errors into an array or collection in java.

Try this one

```
String json = "{\"ACode\": \"aa\",\"RCode\": \"rr\", \"Errors\": \"e1,e2,e3\" }";

class ErrorsDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<String[]> {

    public String[] deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT,
            JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        return ((JsonObject) json).getAsJsonPrimitive("Errors").getAsString().split(",");
    }
}

Gson gson1 = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(String[].class, new ErrorsDeserializer())
        .create();

String[] errors = gson1.fromJson(json, String[].class);
for (String error : errors) {
    System.out.println(error);
}
```

Comment: For more info have a look at [Gson: Directly convert String to JsonObject (no POJO)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4110664/gson-directly-convert-string-to-jsonobject-no-pojo)

Answer (score -1):

you can create a class with variables "ACode","RCode","Errors" then use gson to convert it to that class, CustomObject obj2 = gson.fromJson(json, CustomObject .class);