# Getting the values from a JSON string in Java using GSON

Tags: java, json, string, gson

I hope someone can show me where i'm doing it wrong...

I'm using sendgrid for my email tracking and it is posting a JSON like the following:

```
[
  {
    "email": "john.doe@sendgrid.com",
    "timestamp": 1337966815,
    "event": "click",
    "url": "http://sendgrid.com"
    "userid": "1123",
    "template": "welcome"
  }
]
```

Now i want to get the value of for example for "timestamp" which is 1337966815 . I've tried the following:

```
      StringBuffer jb = new StringBuffer();
      String line = null;
      try {
        BufferedReader reader = req.getReader();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
          jb.append(line);
      } catch (Exception e) { /*report an error*/ }
      String jsonString = jb.toString();
      Gson gson = new Gson();
      JsonObject jsonObject = gson.fromJson(jsonString, JsonObject.class);
      String timeStam = jsonObject.get(timestamp).toString();
```

The string of jsonString gives me the following which i think is in the right format:

```
[  {    "email": "john.doe@sendgrid.com",    "timestamp": 1337966815,    "event": "click",    "url": "http://sendgrid.com"    "userid": "1123",    "template": "welcome"  }]
```

But i'm getting the following error at this line of code - JsonObject jsonObject = gson.fromJson(jsonString, JsonObject.class);

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 52
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it the format of jsonString that is confusing the JsonObject?

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Kind regards
Francois

Comment: is your json  complete ? because it look like jsonArray from those '[' and ']'.

Comment: You have invalid JSON, and it's telling you that. Aside from that, it's questionable how you're using Gson in the first place. If you want a `JsonObject` and not a mapping to a POJO, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4110664/gson-directly-convert-string-to-jsonobject-no-pojo

Comment: Thanks Brian and Amrut for your replies. Yes it's a complete JSON. I think i'm missing JSONParser and am gonna try that.

Comment: This is a JSON Array, not a JSON Object, so why try and deserialize to a JsonObject? Also, why go through the trouble of slurping it all _then_ giving it to a Gson? Gson can do that for you

Comment: Hi fge, what do you mean? Isn't gson requiring a string?

Comment: Of course not it doesn't. Look at [the javadoc](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/index.html?com/google/gson/Gson.html) and see all the defined `.fromJson()` methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON you show in both examples is *invalid*. There is a comma missing after `"url":"http://sendgrid.com"`

Ignoring that, the JSON you show is an **array of JSON objects**, not an object. This is what the `[]` denotes (correcting the missing comma):

```
[
  {
    "email": "john.doe@sendgrid.com",
    "timestamp": 1337966815,
    "event": "click",
    "url": "http://sendgrid.com",
    "userid": "1123",
    "template": "welcome"
  }
]
```

If you are not mapping this JSON to a Java POJO, then you would want to use Gson's [JsonParser](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonParser.html) to parse your `String` to a [JsonElement](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonElement.html) (Note you could even use it to parse directly from the Stream, but this if for how you have your code now).

```
JsonElement je = new JsonParser().parse(jsonString);
```

Now you have what's called a "parse tree". This `JsonElement` is the root. To access it as an array you're going to do:

```
JsonArray myArray = je.getAsJsonArray();
```

You only show this array containing one object, but let's say it could have more than one. By iterating through the array you can do:

```
for (JsonElement e : myArray)
{
    // Access the element as a JsonObject
    JsonObject jo = e.getAsJsonObject();

    // Get the `timestamp` element from the object
    // since it's a number, we get it as a JsonPrimitive
    JsonPrimitive tsPrimitive = jo.getAsJsonPrimitive("timestamp");

    // get the primitive as a Java long
    long timestamp = tsPrimitive.getAsLong();
    System.out.println("Timestamp: " + timestamp);
}
```

Realize that Gson *primarily* is meant for Object Relational Mapping where you want to take that JSON and have it converted to a Java object. This is actually a *lot* simpler:

```
public class ResponseObject {
    public String email;
    public long timestamp;
    public String event;
    public String url;
    public String userid;
    public String template;
}
```

Because you have array of these, you want to use a `TypeToken` and `Type` to indicate your JSON is a `List` of these `ResponseObject` objects:

```
Type myListType = new TypeToken<List<ResponseObject>>(){}.getType();
List<ResponseObject> myList = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, myListType);
```