# Parse Json from Java properties file using gson library

Tags: java, json, gson, properties-file

I need to read and parse a json array from java properties file. I'm able to read the properties file and get the json array String. But I'm unable to parse the json array and get the values. I'm using gson library. Here is the data from properties file

```
jsonarray = [ { key1 : value1, key2 : value2 } ]
```

Code:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(new FileInputStream(filePath));
String jsonArray = properties.getProperty("jsonarray")
JsonElement element = new JsonPrimitive(jsonArray);
JsonArray array = element.getAsJsonArray();
```

I'm getting IllegalStateException

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not a JSON Array: "[ { key1 : value1, key2 : value2 } ]"
```

The problem is it is taking extra double quotes at the beginning and at the end.

I have tried adding quotes to keys and values, but with no success. I need to use gson library itself, so please don't suggest other libraries. I cannot create a POJO class for it and use `new Gson().fromJson(jsonArray)`, so kindly please don't suggest that also.

I've searched and tried a lot without success. The method I referred is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4110664/gson-directly-convert-string-to-jsonobject-no-pojo/22083425#22083425)

Thanks in advance

Edit 1: I've tried the following in properties file

```
jsonarray = [ { "key1" : "value1", "key2" : "value2" } ]
```

and I got same exception like

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not a JSON Array: "[ { \"key1\" : \"value1\", \"key2\" : \"value2\" } ]"
```

I tried to create a JsonArray object in code and print it

```
JsonArray array = new JsonArray();
JsonObject object = new JsonObject();
object.addProperty("key1", "value1");
object.addProperty("key2", "value2");
array.add(object);
System.out.println(array.toString());
```

The output was as below

```
[{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}]
```

Comment: this is not a valid json format . it should be like [{"key1": "valu1","key2":"value2"}]

Comment: Yes, I've tried that also. Does space matter? I had put spaces before and after colon

Comment: No space will not make any difference but quotation marks will

Comment: you should send an input like this [{\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key2\":\"value2\"]} as java string

Comment: Your data should be like **{ "key1" : "value1", "key2" : "value2" }**  Check here https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=d8410952f64e88bd8296f0808c25ed50

Comment: @cool, @alpesh,  I tried [ { \"key1\" : \"value1\" , \"key2\" : \"value2\" } ], I got error as `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not a JSON Array: "[ { \"key1\" : \"value1\", \"key2\" : \"value2\" } ]"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Javadoc of `JsonPrimitive`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/JsonPrimitive.html#JsonPrimitive-java.lang.String-) you've used here

```
JsonElement element = new JsonPrimitive(jsonArray);
```

states

> Create a primitive containing a String value.

When you then do

```
JsonArray array = element.getAsJsonArray();
```

it'll obviously fail because `element` is a JSON String, not a JSON array. Just parse the JSON directly

```
JsonArray array = new Gson().fromJson(jsonArray, JsonArray.class)
```

---

This is all after you've changed your properties file content to be actual JSON

```
jsonarray = [ { "key1" : "value1", "key2" : "value2" } ]
```