# Deserialize string value json to generic java object

Tags: java, json, apache-kafka, gson

I have records coming in ConsumerRecords for kafka consumer. I have to iterate through the ConsumerRecord and convert string(json) value to generic type object. Please help how this can be done. I don't want to use ClassName but generic type.

```
for (ConsumerRecord<Integer, String> cr : records) {
                String str = cr.value();
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                ClassName dto = gson.fromJson(str, ClassName.class);
            }
        }
```

Now I did some changes and wrote the code as below which seems to work fine. Please suggest if there is any flaw in it:

```
for (ConsumerRecord<Integer, String> cr : records) {
                String str = cr.value();
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                Object dto = gson.fromJson(str, Object.class);
                System.out.println(dto);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I have edited it with the code.

Comment: Write a custom deserializer.

Comment: The only generic types (built into Java) you can use are LinkedHashMap or TreeMap. Without showing your messages to us, that's the best you can do here... Also, please move Gson variable out of the loop

Comment: Or create a plain JsonObject https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4110664/gson-directly-convert-string-to-jsonobject-no-pojo

Comment: Why downvote? Instead you can ask questioner to modify the question.

Comment: As said by @PrashantPandey you may want to write custom SERDE

Comment: Thanks Prashant, cricket_007 and Ashish. I will try your suggestions and post here about which one worked.