# how to convert the string to JSON?

Tags: java, android, json, string, gson

```
private IBeaconListener createIBeaconListener() {
        return new SimpleIBeaconListener() {
            @Override
            public void onIBeaconDiscovered(IBeaconDevice ibeacon, IBeaconRegion region) {
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                String json = gson.toJson(ibeacon);

                Gson gson2 = new Gson();
                String deviceId = "{deviceId : 67814f71b5bdb4d3}";
                String json2 = gson2.toJson(obj);

                Log.i("Beacon", "IBeacon discovered: " + json);
                Log.i("Gateway", "Gateway discovered: " + json2);

                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        publish(json + json2);
                    }
                }, 5000);
            }
        };
    }
```

I want to convert *deviceId* to JSON Object so that I can publish it together with *json*. Does anyone know how to do it?
This is the result I got:

```
{"address":"05:B2:68:5B:BC:92","batteryPower":-1,"distance":2.0765944282461007E9,"firmwareVersion":"-1","hashCodeBuilder":{"iConstant":37,"iTotal":17},"major":1,"minor":0,"proximity":"FAR","proximityUUID":"2686f39c-bada-4658-854a-a62e7e5e8b8d","rssi":-94,"shuffled":false,"timestamp":1680527328760,"txPower":11}"{deviceId : 67814f71b5bdb4d3}"
```

However, I want the output to be like this:

```
{"address":"05:B2:68:5B:BC:92","batteryPower":-1,"distance":2.0765944282461007E9,"firmwareVersion":"-1","hashCodeBuilder":{"iConstant":37,"iTotal":17},"major":1,"minor":0,"proximity":"FAR","proximityUUID":"2686f39c-bada-4658-854a-a62e7e5e8b8d","rssi":-94,"shuffled":false,"timestamp":1680527328760,"txPower":11,"deviceId":"67814f71b5bdb4d3"}
```

Comment: Based on question title you may be looking for [Gson: Directly convert String to JsonObject (no POJO)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4110664). But based on `String json2 = gson2.toJson(obj);` I am not sure what you want to achieve...

Comment: So it looks like you want to create *single* JSON structure containing data from two JSON objects. In that case create `JsonObject` representing first JSON (here `String json`) and add to it new property representing *deviceId* : *67814f71b5bdb4d3* (like `jsonObject.addProperty("deviceId", "67814f71b5bdb4d3")`). Then convert it back to String and publish that String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a `Gateway` class object and used `gson` on it. The following code example worked for me:

```
public class Gateway {
    private String deviceId;

    public Gateway(String deviceId) {
        this.deviceId = deviceId;
    }

    public String getDeviceId() { return deviceId; }

    public void setDeviceId(String deviceId) {
        this.deviceId = deviceId;
    }
}

Gateway gateway = new Gateway("67814f71b5bdb4d3");
Gson gson2 = new Gson();
String json2 = gson2.toJson(gateway);
```

Answer (score 0):

Code is not clear for me but you can try something like this

```
    String json = gson.toJson(ibeacon);

   JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json );

    try {
        jsonObj.put("deviceId", "67814f71b5bdb4d3");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    String myJSON = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
```

Comment: I modified the code try now.